# Which is better to use, Magento's new responsive design or Waterlee boilerplate?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I would like to know, when building a responsive theme for Magento, which is a better choice to go with, Magento's new default responsive-design theme or [Waterlee, a Foundation-based Magento boilerplate theme](http://waterlee.jakesharp.co/)?

Thanks!

Comment: are we talking about Magento 2.0?

Comment: 1.9.0.1 Is there a 2.0 beta or something? I hadn't seen it. If 2.0 is better to go with, I'd like to know.

Comment: it's not, it's in beta

Comment: @JulienLachal. It's not even in beta. It's alpha.

Comment: Ok. Then, I would like to know for 1.9.0.1. Cheers.

Comment: my bad Marius ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 'it depends'.  [Waterlee](http://waterlee.jakesharp.co/) is built on Zurb/Foundation so if you are familiar with and/or prefer working with Zurb then it can be a great choice.  There is also [webcomm's boilerplate](https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate) built in Bootstrap3 if you are looking to compare community themes built on responsive frameworks for Magento.

Magento's 1.9 RWD theme is responsive and the theme overall has made a number of improvements over the default theme in 1.8 so it too can be a good choice.

I would suggest taking a look at your design especially the navigation and see how your plan to make your new site look on desktop, tablet, and mobile fits with those theme options.  Other factors to consider may be how pages like My Account and the Checkout process for those themes work and match up with your sites plan.

Comment: Thank you. I based my design on Foundation, and from what I understand, Waterlee has a full grid, unlike the new RWD default theme, so I think I will go with Waterlee. I just wanted to make sure there was no glaring reason to or not to. Thanks again.

Comment: @b_d_m_p I'm looking for a good boilerplate responsive theme as well. Did you build your site on top of Waterlee? Is there a link you can share?

Comment: @monocat Yes, I used Waterlee. http://waterlee.jakesharp.co/ It is very good. I would recommend it.